# how to write user input in whatsapp sharing message

Tags: javascript, html

In my website I have a whatsapp sharing button, so i want to send my website link with a parameter,

For e.g.

> abcd.com/?name=**userinput**

This is the code of whatsapp sharing button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var userinput=prompt("Please Enter Your Name");
</script>
<script><a href="whatsapp://send?text= Link abcd.html?name="><b>share on whatsapp</b></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

JS:

```
<script>
    //Ask the user for name and store it on name variable
    var name = prompt("Please Enter Your Name");

    //This will be called when the link is clicked
    function sendWhatsapp(){
        var url     = "www.abcd.com/?name=" + name;
        var sMsg    = encodeURIComponent( "hi this is " + name + " and my link is " + url );
        var whatsapp_url = "whatsapp://send?text=" + sMsg;
        window.location.href = whatsapp_url;
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<a onclick="sendWhatsapp()">share on whatsapp</a>
```

---

**FULL HTML CODE:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    //Ask the user for name and store it on name variable
    var name = prompt("Please Enter Your Name");

    //This will be called when the link is clicked
    function sendWhatsapp(){
        var url     = "www.abcd.com/?name=" + name;
        var sMsg    = encodeURIComponent( "hi this is " + name + " and my link is " + url );
        var whatsapp_url = "whatsapp://send?text=" + sMsg;
        window.location.href = whatsapp_url;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a onclick="sendWhatsapp()">share on whatsapp</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How will it work, sir can you please explain me with full code.
i mean by creating a short html code

Comment: I added a full HTML code. Please check. I already added notes on the codes above.

Comment: Thankyou very much sir

Comment: sir it's output is ► www.abcd.com/?name=userinput

but i want to show like this.
► hi this is **userinput** and my link is www.abcd.com/?name?userinput

Comment: Please accept my answer by clicking the check if this helped you.